# How to create a where expression in nested entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following EF query:

```
Checklist checklist = await context.Checklist.Where(c => c.CHECKLIST_ID == id)
          .Include("Employee").Include("EmployeeArchive").Include("ChecklistResponses")
          .Include("ChecklistComments").Include("ChecklistResponses.ChecklistQuestion.ChecklistGroup")
          .Include("ChecklistResponses.ChecklistQuestion")
          .Include("ChecklistResponses.Employee").FirstAsync();
```

I want to build a where clause on the ChecklistQuestion entity but that is 3 levels deep and it seems I can not build that in the Where clause as it stands. The ChecklistQuestion is a one-to-many relation to the ChecklistResponses.

What I'm getting back is a single entity Checklist with all of the related entities included.  The ChecklistResponses will have multiple rows.  What I'm trying to do is limit the ChecklistResponses to a ChecklistQuestion.GROUP_ID != 4.

UPDATE: According the Microsoft it is not possible to filter entities with Include with regular Entity Framework.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN#explicitFilter There are two options I have if I can't do this within the Include.  I could filter on the client. (I have a main view with partial views).  Or I could do an explicit Load statement.

Comment: Can you please let us know what are you looking to get back from this query exactly? The "Where" clause indicates a collection of Checklists, but the variable to store it in is a single instance. Then with all the "Includes" it looks like you want a checklist with all related data, and all that data's data as well. Clarify this a bit please as this is hard to reason about, and someone should be able to help you out.

Comment: I added that to my question, thanks.

Comment: You do have a third option, which is doing the final join manually (without .Include, but instead .GroupJoin). This is of course not as flexible as EF with FK mapping, but if your model doesnt change that often, it should be viable. But yes, EF6 does not allow the filtering of included entities and will instead return the whole join result.

Comment: That might be a great option because I am going to have to group by the groups anyway.  I am grouping later in the client because I couldn't figure out how to set it all up front.  I've posted the updated query.

Comment: Basically I would like to do a GroupJoin on the ChecklistResponses.ChecklistQuestion.ChecklistGroup Include because I want to be able to iterate by question group to display a list of survey questions by group.  I actually have this working but am doing the grouping, ordering AFTER I get the result set back.  My other question is whether I should be loading everything up front or not.  I looked at the SQL generated and it's doing a UNION ALL.  The query itself looks pretty solid considering all the Include statements I have.  I tried explicitly loading related entities but seemed slower.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when using LINQ extension methods it's more common to use the lambda expression syntax, so I'll use that. Then, I think you need the "ThenInclude" extension, which will allow what you are looking for. I left out additional Includes to get this more concise.

```cs
Checklist checklist = await context.Checklist.Where(c => c.CHECKLIST_ID == id)             
    .Include(c => c.ChecklistResponses)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.ChecklistResponses.
    .Where(q => q.ChecklistQuestion.GROUP_ID != 4))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: But isn't that the EF Core syntax?

Comment: EF6 and EF Core both support both the LINQ and Lambda queries.  It's a C# feature, not an EF feature. And they are equivalent.